# How to return a value from forEach

Tags: javascript, function

I'm really new to JavaScript, and I've encountered a problem that I don't understand.

I wanted to write function which takes an array as an argument, and returns true if all elements in the array are identical.

By now I know that a simple for loop is more effective, but I wanted to do this simple function with *forEach()*.

```
function isUniform(array) {
    let uniChecker = array[0];
    array.forEach(function(element) {
        if (uniChecker !== element) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

It always returns true, even if it should return false.

Comment: returning in forEach does nothing ... use array.some/array.every (whichever is appropriate ... I think it's `return array.every(element => uniChecker === element)`

Comment: With your current approach you would have set a flag like `var isUni = true;`, then set it to false inside your `forEach` function, then finally `return isUni;`

Comment: You are returning `false` from the wrong function. You think you are returning `false` from `isUniform`, when in reality you are returning `false` from inside the `forEach` function. Instead of forEach, use a `for` loop, that won't create a function inside a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> forEach() throws away return values and always returns undefined

so no matter what you do inside your code the return value from forEach is  never returned

You can create a flag that sets to false when your condition is met(Its a suggestion if you want to go with ForEach)

```js
function isUniform(array) {
 let flag=true;
    let uniChecker = array[0];
    array.forEach(function(element) {
        if (uniChecker !== element) {
          flag=false;
        }
    });
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: The fact you need a flag to solve this problem with `forEach` should be enough of an indicator that it's not the right tool for the job. A native `for` loop would be an improvement on `forEach` given you can at least exit early.

Comment: I have especially mentioned that's why (its  a hack,suggestion  only) .Otherwise rest other answers are better for the task @James

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately returning from the `forEach` callback does nothing to the outer scope, it simply exits the callback scope. While `forEach` *can* be used it's not the most efficient as there's no real way of exiting the loop early.

Better alternatives would be [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) / [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), these functions are designed to test items in an array and detect anomalies (determined by whatever condition you provide) and exit on the first mismatch e.g.

```
const isUniform = arr => arr.every(x => arr[0] === x)
```

**Playground**

```js
const arr = [1,1,3,1,1,2]
// using `every` (recommended)
console.log(`Using 'every'...`);
let isUniform = arr => arr.every(x => {
  console.log(`Testing ${x}`);
  return arr[0] === x;
});
console.log(isUniform(arr));
// using `some` (bit more complicated but can still work)
console.log(`Using 'some'...`);
isUniform = arr => !arr.some(x => {
  console.log(`Testing ${x}`);
  return arr[0] !== x;
});
console.log(isUniform(arr));
```

Answer (score 4):

The easy way, you change to for loop because in `forEach` return nothing

```
function isUniform(array) {
    let uniChecker = array[0];
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if (uniChecker !== array[i]) {

            return false;
        }
    };
    return true;
}
```

```js
function isUniform(array) {
    let uniChecker = array[0];
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if (uniChecker !== array[i]) {
            
            return false;
        }
    };
    return true;
}

var a = [2, 2,3];
console.log(isUniform(a));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add the return false into `forEach`, you are not able to get the correct value of checked. Use for loop so you can add break anytime you found your item:

```
function isUniform(array) {
  let uniChecker = array[0];
  var isChecked = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (uniChecker !== array[i]) {
      isChecked = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return isChecked;
}
```

Or you can use [`some`](http://[1]:%20https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/some) or [`every`](http://[1]:%20https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/some) to test if item exists into array.

```
function isUniform(array) {
  return array.some(x => array[0] === x);
}
```

Comment: Although it works and corrects OP's code, there is a performance problem with this approach. `forEach` will always traverse the whole array. If the array is 10.000 elements long and just the first two elements aren't identical, your script will uselessly compare 9998 elements instead of immediately returning false. A `for` loop, on the other hand, can be interrupted with `break;`.

Answer (score 2):

**ES6**

Obviously as  we have ES6 available all over the place you can use [Array Every Prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'].every( (el, index, arr) => el === arr[0] )
```

```js
//For NON-ES6 way

function allItemsAreEqual(elements) {
  return new Set(elements).size == 1;
}

console.log(allItemsAreEqual(['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'])) // true
```

Comment: Nice approach using `new Set(elements).size`

Answer (score 1):

```
const checkIfAllEqual = inputArray => inputArray.every( value => value === inputArray[0] )
```

checkIfAllEqual( [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5] )  will return true.

Answer (score 1):

The `forEach` function doesn't return a the value you're expecting it to ([docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)), which means that your `isUniform` function will always return `true`. For what you're trying to do, you could use an old-fashioned `for` loop, or use `array.every(isTheSame)`.

### Using a `for` loop

```
function isUniform(array) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] !== array[0]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

### Using `array.every`

```
function isUniform(array) {
    // Returns true if for every item in the array, the callback
    // (item === array[0]) evaluates to true
    return array.every(item => item === array[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a destructuring an take the first element and iterate the rest and return early.

```
function isUniform([a, rest]) {
    return rest.every(b => a === b);
}
```